# C# split string after each # symbol

Tags: c#, string, split

i was wondering is there's only one way ( regex ) to split string after each # symbol
here's how looks result, which i want to split in string variables
27173316#sometext.balbalblabba#4849489#text#text2#number
I want to past each value before # in string variable or array

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can just use [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx):

```
string input = "27173316#sometext.balbalblabba#4849489#text#text2#number";
string[] values = input.Split('#');
```

Comment: damn, so easy. thanks a bunch!

Comment: @NikolaD-Nick: The funny thing is how votes get distributed by reputation, i.e. that who has the most gets the most upvotes, even though all answers are effectively the same.

Answer (score 8):

No, you don't need to use a regular expression:

```
string[] values = input.Split('#');
```

Answer (score 8):

Use the `string.Split()` method.

```
string[] myArray = input.Split('#');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the original string and your Splitting character and ca split the string...

```
string origInput = "yout values with # and other sign"
char[] splitCode = new char[]{'#'}; //if you have more then one split sign you can add here
string[] output = origInput.Split(splitCode,StringSplitOptions.None);
```